# jquery to show div one by one each click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

This is my code :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.toAdd').hide();
        $('#add').click(function () {
            var i = 0;
            $('.toAdd').each(function () {
                if ($(this).show()) {
                    i++;
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div id=add><input type="button" value="click"/>
    </div>
    <div id="toAdd">
    <label>1</label>
    </div>
    <div id="toAdd">
    <label>2</label>
    </div>
    <div id="toAdd">
    <label>3</label>
    </div>
    <div id="toAdd">
    <label>4</label>
    </div>
```

In this code i need to show div one by one  for each click event but its not working?

Comment: First of all 'toAdd' is id, and you used it as a class in jQuery.
Use '#' instead of '.'

Comment: Actually, use `class` instead of `id`.

Comment: yes i changed but its not working that whole divisions was at single click event

Comment: Why do you have `$(this).show()` in an `if`? It doesn't return a true/false value, it just returns the jQuery object, so that methods can be chained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ID** must be **unique**, use **classes** instead.

```
$('.toAdd').hide();

var count = 0;
$('input').on('click',function(){
    $('.toAdd:eq('+count+')').show();
    count++;
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuQCq/1)

Comment: There should be no space before `:eq`.

Comment: @Barmar yes, It's typo. Tnx

Comment: @Vucko what if I want to show 3 items at a time, how do i construct that? thank you

Answer (score 2):

In your divs change id="toAdd" to class="toAdd"

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you need to change `id="toAdd"` to `class="toAdd".

You can then show the first unhidden DIV with:

```
    $('#add input').click(function () {
        $('.toAdd:hidden:first').show();
    });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/uuQCq/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<div id="toAdd"> with <div class="toAdd">`

and do this

```
  $('.toAdd').each(function () {
                if (!$(this.is(":visible"))) {
                   $(this).show();
                   break;
                }
            });
```

Comment: No, it would check if the div is hidden. If hidden it would make it visible. and since only one div is to be made visible, break is used!!!

Comment: Seems like a pretty awkward way to go about it.  I like the other answers a lot better.

Comment: I don't see your answer here

Comment: Well, no, when there's already a very fine answer posted, then the question's already been answered, hasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

change id to class, like other have said and if you need to cycle the show/hide. then this might come handy

```
 $('.toAdd').hide();
 var i = 0;
 $('#add input').click(function () {
     i=(i >= 4)?0:i;
      //or if(i >= 4){ i=0;}
     $('.toAdd').eq(i).show().siblings().not(':first').hide();
     i++;

 });
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/th8rj/1/)